# How can I see if there’s motion in one room from another?

Tags: led, motion-sensor

I want to setup a motion sensor in a particular room and have a small LED or something turn on in another room. Is this even possible? Ideally battery powered and wireless.

Comment: "Is this even possible?" Yes.

Comment: Sure, motion sensors are designed to turn on lights.  Doesn't say which size.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica any size even a massive 10000 candlepower searchlight if using a relay.

Comment: Doppler motion sensor work through drywall if no insulation inside.

Comment: Search for "mailbox alarm" for an OTS solution.